# change image format of image object in opencl

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I have written a small code to create an image object in opencl as below:

```
img_fmt.image_channel_order = CL_R;
img_fmt.image_channel_data_type = CL_UNSIGNED_INT8;      
memobj_in_luma = clCreateImage2D(p->context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, &img_fmt, p->width, p->height, 0, NULL, &ret);
```

After creating this object I want to change the image format to CL_RGBA. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with CUDA.  Removing CUDA tag.

Comment: Thanks for the straight answer. Is there any reference where I can see this? Actually I am receiving a directx surface with image format CL_R and I want to change this to CL_RGBA to access four pixels in one memory access. This help in performance improvement.

Comment: I tried this. When I create image with this RGBA, I cannot copy the contents of the original surface. Actually clEnqueueCopyImage gets failed.

Comment: Here is the link to that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111760/changing-image-format-of-a-directx-acquired-surface-in-opencl

Comment: Yoiu can create an image from a buffer, where you tell it what the format is. Perhaps you could create two images from the same buffer with two different formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the discussion in comments above:
We can't change the image format of already created image.We need to create another image for different format required.
Also, I posted my question in intel [forums](https://software.intel.com/en-us/comment/1836291#comment-1836291) and got the same answer.